# Can I reverse my transformation of an XML file and get back the original?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xsd, libxml2

Suppose I have a abc.xml and a sample.xsl which transforms my abc.xml to 123.xml.

Now given the transformed XML and the stylesheet sample.xsl is there a way to get back my original abc.xml file.

Is it possible to achieve this using XSLT?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5497146/1987598 and [You mean that given an omelette and a frying pan, you want to reconstruct three eggs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488263/work-backwards-from-an-xslt-to-create-an-xml#comment32441239_21488263). By the way, tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Perhaps the discussion would be more fruitful if you could explain _why_ you need to reverse a transformation?

Answer (score 2):

> given the transformed XML and the stylesheet sample.xsl is there a way
>   to get back my original abc.xml file.

This is theoretically impossible, because information may be (and very often is) discarded during the first transformation. Here's a trivial example:

**Original XML**

```
<input>123.4567</input>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="round(input)" />
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>123</output>
```

As you can see, the original fractional part, `.4567`, is nowhere in the result nor in the stylesheet.

In certain (simple) cases you can make an educated guess regarding the contents of the original XML document, but no more than that.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthias already said, this is (usually) not possible. Suppose this is your input XML:

```
<hello>world</hello>
```

And you transform that using the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="hello"><world>Not here!</world></xsl:template>
```

This will produce the following XML:

```
<world>Not here!</world>
```

Obviously, there is no roundtrip conversion possible in this case, the resulting XML is (usually) a text file and it does not contain any kind of meta-information of prior to the conversion. However, if your conversion has some way to make the roundtrip possible, for instance by adding the original XML, then it becomes a trivial excercise:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <original-xml>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </original-xml>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    <result>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can get your original file back by doing:

```
<xsl:template match="original-xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

A waste of resources, if you ask me, but if that is the requirement... (though, a warning up front, a copy of XML is not always 100% equal to the original due to whitespace stripping, order of attributes and line-end handling).

Another way of doing this is perhaps by storing the original URI to your source document, which, if not moved, can be used to reconstruct the original by simply pointing to that file.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I needed this in one of my work items. So if I have to achieve this, the only possible way would be write another XSL file, which transforms 123.xml to abc.xml. So I would need two XSL files. In my program I will have an idea on what my XML will be transformed into so I think I can write another XSL file which would does reverse translation and get my content back

Comment: @Bose, that is one way of doing it. You can also simply create a file that maintains locations of new and old, and then you do not need this transformation at all, just retrieve the old file. You do not need two XSLT files, but it is probably easier that way.

Comment: @Bose, but more importantly, you should ask yourself (or your boss) why you need this (see Matthias's comment, which is yet unanswered). There may be better ways here, but you have given too little to go on to help you better....

Comment: Thanks Abel, I will add more details here tomorrow after discussing internally. Yes really need some good suggestions here to solve this issue but before that I feel some discussion is needed internally as well.